# Including node.js into my html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-api

I know I am going to sound very noobish for asking this question BUT is there an easy way to include node.js in my html or some Google API library I can include.

Like:

```
 <script>google.load(xxxx)</script>

  **or** 
  <script src="xxxx"></script>
```

I know this is the second sucky question I have asked this week but... I have to learn somewhere right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to include node.js? If you explain what you're trying to achieve (what do you think node.js will do for you?) you might get some more specific advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node isn't a library you can require. It is a C/C++ application that you run on the server. You can require individual libraries, if they don't depend on a native Node library, and one thing to look into there is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) which gives you the ability to `require('foo')` like you can in Node.

--URL corrected above